# CodeWithMosh: building the listing screen Padding problem with iOS and Android not outputting the same result

Tags: android, ios, react-native, padding

In his video, in the last part, he says that at the time of his Recording in **iOS** the padding is not applying when he applies it in the Screen component, but it actually works on Android. **And at the end, when you do exactly what he suggests, a double layer of padding is added in the Android version.**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View,  SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function SafeScreen({children, style}) {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[styles.screen, style]}>
            <View style={style}>{children}</View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        flex: 1,
    }
})

export default SafeScreen;
```

*I did find the Fix myself so look at my answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Fix that I did:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function SafeScreen({children, style}) {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.screen ,style]}>{children}</View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        flex: 1,
    },
})

export default SafeScreen;
```

Just simply don't use the **SafeAreaView** by React Native and instead apply the screen styling to the **View**.